# addchild not displaying content

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, mxml, mxmlc

In the following code i dont have any error but why is that the addchild(video); i.e, the the video captured by webcam is not displayed

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">


<mx:Script>
<![CDATA[
import org.com.figurew;
import mx.controls.Button;
import mx.controls.Alert;
import flash.display.InteractiveObject;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.media.*;
import flash.net.*;


public function addBody():void
{

var ret:Number = figurew.getInstance().getparam();
if( ret == 1)
{
 Alert.show("Camera detected");

}
if(ret == 0)
{
 Alert.show("No camera detected");
} 
var cam:Camera =  Camera.getCamera();
if(cam != null)
{ 
 cam.setMode(640, 480, 30);
 var video:Video = new Video(30, 40);
 video.attachCamera(cam);

 addChild(video);


}
else
{

 trace("No Camera Detected");

 }

}


  ]]>

 </mx:Script>
 <mx:Button label="Test camera" click="addBody();"  x="99" y="116"/>

 </mx:Application >
```

**figurew.as**

```
 package org.com
 {
 import flash.display.InteractiveObject;
 import flash.display.Sprite;
 import flash.media.*;
 import flash.net.*;


 public class figurew extends Sprite
 {
  public function figurew()
  {
 //getparam();
 var cam:Camera =  Camera.getCamera();
 if(cam != null)
 { 
  cam.setMode(640, 480, 30);
  var video:Video = new Video(300, 450);
  video.attachCamera(cam);

  addChild(video);


 }
else
{

 trace("No Camera Detected");

}

}
public function getparam():Number
{ 
 var cam:Camera =  Camera.getCamera();
 if(cam != null)
 { 
 cam.setMode(640, 480, 30);
 var video:Video = new Video(300, 450);
 video.attachCamera(cam);

 addChild(video);
 return 1;

 }
 else
 {
 return 0;
 trace("No Camera Detected");

 }
  }
 private static var _instance:figurew = null;

 public static function getInstance():cldAS
 {
 if(_instance == null)
 {
 trace("No instance found");
 _instance = new cldAS();
 }
 return _instance;

 } 
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see no place where you set a height or width of the video child of your main application.  That may be an issue.

You have an MX Button tag inside the script tag.  I suspect this will cause a compilation error.  So it is possible that you're viewing an "old" Version of your code.  Fix the errors and recompile and relaunch.

Comment: <mx: button tag insid ehte script was a cut and paste error.Can u please tell me how to set the height and width of the  and which comes up next to the button

Comment: video.height = someheight and video.width = somewidth.  You can also use the setACtualSize method.  Ideally you should be sizing your child in updateDisplayList().  Setting the height and width has nothing to do w/ the button, so i'm not sure what you're asking me there.